# jquery fail hide and show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I trying to hide and show a  base on dropdownlist selection but fail,no idea where i did wrong,please help..

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#code').on('change', function () {
             if (this.value == 'T4')
             {
                 $("#TR").show();
             }
             else {
                 $("#TR").hide();
             }
         });
     });

       <div class="form-group" style='display:none;' id='TR'>
        <label for="Training Fees(RM)" style="color:black">Training Fees(RM)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"ID="RM_TEXT" placeholder="RINGGIT" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

my dropdownlist     :

```
         <div>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="Code" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

my dropdownlist DataTextField and DataValueField:
[image: DROPDOWNLIST]

Comment: can you please provide fiddle or plunker that reproduce the same case?

Comment: Did you try putting console.log(this.value) inside change handler?

Comment: reason is ID which you are using is not #code after rendering kindly change your ID by inspect element.See my answer below if it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id reference is miss matched. You have defined "Code" but attached listener to "code".

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Code" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Use same case in both places

```
$('#code').on('change', function () {
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly Check DropDown list ID in inspect element,try to put something if your are using master page then ID will be **ct100_**

OR use

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Code" runat="server" onchange="javascript:return dropdown(this);"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Javascirpt

```
 function dropdown(val)
    {
      if ($(val).val() == 'T4') {
        $("#TR").show();
      }
      else {
                 $("#TR").hide();
      }
    }
```

Comment: The issue is due to the wrong id reference used to attached the change handler

Comment: Yes,that is also the case, but it will only work if not using any master page whereas mine will work in both case :).I think somebody down voted my answer :(